# Is textwatch a interface?

Tags: android, extends, implements

when i implements textwatcher, a error occur

```
Syntax error on token "implements", extends expected
```

my code is

```
import android.text.TextWatcher;
public interface Testing implements TextWatcher{

}
```

why i need to use extends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not *implementing* `TextWatcher` - you're creating a new interface which extends it.

So you would write:

```
public interface Testing extends TextWatcher
```

or

```
public class Testing implements TextWatcher
```

You haven't said what you're really trying to do, so we can't tell whether you should actually be declaring a class, or just declaring a new interface which extends `TextWatcher`.

See [section 9.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3) of the JLS for more details of declaring one interface to extend another.